# Is this a good use case for a util class?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have the same `Ember.$ajax` call being used in several locations in my Ember app. I chose to use a `util` class:

```
export default function updateImage(model, token, imageUrl) {
  return Ember.$.ajax({
    url: `api/v1/${Ember.Inflector.inflector.pluralize(model.get('constructor.modelName'))}/${model.get('id')}/update-image`,
    type: 'PUT',
    headers: {
      // Used in staging and production
      // In Development, this will send with an empty value. API ignores this header in development anyways
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': Ember.$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
      Authorization:  `Token ${token }`
    },
    data: {
      data: {
        attributes: {
          'image-url': imageUrl
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Then in a controller/route, I can do:

```
  updateImage(user, this.currentSession.get('token'), imageUrl)
  .success(response => {
    user.set('imageUrl', response['users']['image-url']);
    this.flashService.generic('Saved image!');
  })
  .error(response => {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

Is this good use of a `util` class? Can I refactor this further? Or should I consider some other pattern? Will a mixin be more appropriate for this kind of logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly fine use case. It is single, universal method that can be used across your application. If you would need to use more similar, related methods in many places, or you would want to split `updateImage` function for better abstraction then you should switch to `Mixin`, but now, it's fine.